# View for class/subclass objects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Step 2 in my quest for today is creating ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor views that are able to handle class-subclass objects. So i want a form/page that can handle Person -> Woman or Person -> Man based on the selection of a DropDownList (Man/Woman).

The stuff is stored in the database using EF 4.1 Code First. Which works fine. Cause when I store a Woman, and I retrieve with `context.Person.Where(p => p.Id == 1)` it gets me a Woman object.

The problem I have is that I don't know what to use as a Model in the view.Person would be the most obvious, but then how would I be able to show/access/store the properties for Woman/Man. And in case of a create, the type is not known before hand (server side). The user can select either a Woman/Man, and expects to fill out the specific properties of a Woman or Man.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989674/storing-objects-with-code-first-that-are-related-as-classes-and-subclasses) for the model.

Comment: There are two approaches that I see: 
1) you deliver an HTML page that **doesn't** download additional properties, and 
2) you will download additional properties via an AJAX request from your HTML page.

In case 1, you need a special sort of model which is a superset of both `Man` and `Woman` properties.
In case 2, you need to create separate models for the 'initial' view (the model will be `Person`), and for those AJAX-loaded properties (the models will be `Man` and `Woman` there).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a separate partial view for Man and Woman, then load both views into divs on your page.  Then use jquery to Hide/Show the divs after the drop down list selection changes.